# Bounds of integration after a general rotation in 2D?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I have the integral

$\int_h^\infty dx \int_d^e dy \ e^{-ax^2+cxy-by^2}$

I want to solve this by using a general coordinate rotation

$x= x^\prime  cos\theta-y^\prime sin\theta$

$y= x^\prime  sin\theta+y^\prime cos\theta$

where the angle $\theta$ is chosen so that the cross term in the exponential is zero. It's not important for my question, but this angle happens to be $\theta=\frac{1}{2} arccot(\frac{a-b}{c})$. After the rotation I can do the x and y integrals separately:

$\int dx \ exp(-x^2(a\cos^2\theta-c\cos\theta\sin\theta+b\sin^2\theta))\int dy \ \times \\exp (-y^2(a\cos^2\theta+c\cos\theta\sin\theta+b\sin^2\theta))$

My question is how do I determine the bounds of integration on the integrals after the rotation?

More generally how would I determine the change in integration bounds for an integral $\int^a_b dx \int^c_d dy f(x,y)$ under the general rotation given above?

Comment: So the original domain of integration is a rectangle that is infinite in one dimension?  If so, you're probably hosed.  The rotated rectangle doesn't have boundaries that go along lines of constant coordinates. This means that the best you could do is have one of the bounds of integration be a function instead of a constant.

Comment: First you need an assumption like $c^2<4ac$, else the integral does not converge. Take for example $a=b=c=0$. Next, assuming that, you make a linear change of variables so the quadratic form in the exponent becomes $-x^2-y^2$. Dont use trigonometric functions, just  linear algebra. This will simplify the integral but not solve it, as commented above. The problem is that you will be integrating a nice gaussian, but  on a funny shaped region, like an infinite parallelogram.